# Can a Knock spell open the door to Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Assuming that a Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion is conjured and the entrance is closed, could a creature make use of the Knock spell to open the door to the mansion?

Would the gateway be not considered as an object that Knock can interact with?

Would the creatures get immediately expelled even if the entrance is open (since they were not designated to be allowed inside the mansion at the time of casting)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### *Knock* cannot open the portal to a *Magnificent Mansion*.

From *Magnificent Mansion*:

> You conjure an extradimensional dwelling in range that lasts for the duration. You choose where its one entrance is located. The entrance shimmers faintly and is 5 feet wide and 10 feet tall. You and any creature you designate when you cast the spell can enter the extradimensional dwelling as long as the portal remains open. You can open or close the portal if you are within 30 feet of it. While closed, the portal is invisible.

Let's first assume that you overcome the fact that the Mansion's portal is invisible with a *See Invisibility* spell (which is reasonable, since *Knock* and *See Invisibility* are of the same level).

Now, let's take a look at *Knock*:

> Choose an object that you can see within range. The object can be a door, a box, a chest, a set of manacles, a padlock, or another object that contains a mundane or magical means that prevents access.
> **A target that is held shut by a mundane lock or that is stuck or barred becomes unlocked, unstuck, or unbarred.** If the object has multiple locks, only one of them is unlocked.
> **If you choose a target that is held shut with arcane lock, that spell is suppressed for 10 minutes**, during which time the target can be opened and shut normally.
> When you cast the spell, a loud knock, audible from as far away as 300 feet, emanates from the target object.

Emphasis mine. Note that the effect of the *Knock* spell is not to open a door, but to unlock, unstick, or unbar it, allowing it to be opened normally.  If you cast *Knock* on a locked door, the door unlocks but remains closed.  If you cast *Knock* on a closed, unlocked door, the spell has no effect.  In either case, you still need to reach out, turn the knob, and physically open the door.

The portal to the mansion is not barred, stuck, or locked with a mundane lock.  Neither is it locked with an *Arcane Lock* spell.  The *Knock* spell effects doors that are sealed by these means, and only these means.  The portal to the Magnificent Mansion is not locked, barred, stuck, or sealed with an *Arcane Lock*.  It is simply closed.  Therefore, *Knock* will have no effect on it, just as *Knock* has no effect when cast on a door that is closed but unlocked.

Comment: Great answer -- what *is* the mechanism that keeps creatures that weren't designated at casting time from entering the extradimensional space?

Comment: @AC The mere fact that they were not designated.

Comment: I think you could say the portal doesn't prevent entry, but it doesn't provide it either, unless designated. It doesn't keep people out, because normally it would not be possible to enter the mansion. However, it doesn't go out of it's way to bend space to allow them access unless they are designated... It might make sense to allow a hitchhiker to enter through the portal with a designated creature, in some cases. The spell seems to imply that items get teleported (or rather, doesn't exclude them), so you imagine that it works like other teleports or portals with tagalongs...

Answer (score 7):

**No.** I'm basing this on [Knock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/knock)'s requirement:

> Choose an object that you can see within range.

and from [Magnificent Mansion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magnificent-mansion):

> While closed, the portal is invisible.

Since you cannot see the entrance to the dwelling, it is not a valid target for the Knock spell. Even if somehow you did open the portal, RAI seems to be that you would not be able to enter (unless you were designated by the caster of Magnificent Mansion):

> You and any creature you designate when you cast the spell can enter
>   the extradimensional dwelling

Comment: Fully agree - but just for giggles it may be worthwhile to provide an answer assuming someone has See Invisibility running or Truesight.

Comment: I thought about that. My intuition is that you would then be able to open the portal, but that would do you no good (unless the caster designated you as one of the creatures that can enter the dwelling).

Comment: I think you've got good reasoning there and that would be a nice addition to an already clear answer.

Comment: It's questionable whether the *portal* to the magnificent mansion would even be considered an object

Answer (score -2):

Based on the wording of *[knock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/knock)*:

> Choose an object that you can see within range. The object can be a door, a box, a chest, a set of manacles, a padlock, or another object that contains a mundane or magical means that prevents access.

you could have *Knock* reveal the invisible portal to the mansion as that is something which is opened/closed. However,*knock* lists things which require some sort of *key* or *keyword* and as access to the Mansion doesn't I would compare to *[Magic Circle](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-circle)* with how the effect is looking as it were at who is trying to enter and stops them.

In the case with *Magic Circle* I would not allow *Knock* to be used to allow an otherwise blocked creature from entering and similarly I also would not allow Knock to give a creature access to the Mansion.

Comment: What wording exactly are you basing your first sentence on? That should be the Crux of your argument but just a throwaway line. Quote the relevant part and explain how it proves your point. Answers should not be only about "this is how I would rule" without proper backing and evidence.

Comment: "Choose an object that you can see within range. The object can be a door, a box, a chest, a set of Manacles, a padlock, or another object that contains a mundane or magical means that prevents access."

My phrasing definite should be different for what I am trying to say, with there being a difference between things that require a key to get through and things which have other requirements. You are correct however, my answer is more speculative as I haven't dealt with both of those spells together.

Comment: How can Knock reveal an invisible portal?  Its target requirement is "an object that you can see within range".  Are you arguing that a caster with See Invisible or TrueSight active could make it visible to *other* people?  But where in the wording of Knock are you getting the reveal-invisible conclusion?

Comment: The Mansion spell specifically says that  the caster can 'close' the portal making it invisible. Knock as has been discussed above unlocks things to allow them to open, in this case it would mean the portal's invisibility being removed.